# adding a title to a translucent toolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i'm working with an app that uses navigation controller and UITableViewControllers. i wanted to add a toolbar to one of the table views. so using setToolBarHidden i did manage to show the tool bar and set it translucent. However i want to add a title to that toolbar. You might be asking why do that if the toolbar is actually for tools? the answer is my app needs to display a value as long as new cells are being added. i tried adding custom toolbar but it sticks to the navigation bar since it's a table view. any fix to that? (there is no code i guess that i should be showing)

[image]

Note: that's the desired output but the toolbar should be translucent which shouldn't be an issue cause there's a function for that!

Comment: Do you have any images representing your current output, and desired output?   I think I have an idea what you want, but I'm not quite sure

Comment: ya i do have. i'll post the desired output.

Comment: posted an answer to my question. awkward huh?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a backgroundImage which you programmatically create and wher you draw a Text inside.
Use `UIToolbar.setBackgroundImage:forToolbarPosition:barMetrics:`

Comment: so i should be using Quartz and stuff to draw the backgroundImage and add the text to it then put it here ?

Comment: Yes, unfortunatley the toolbar has no totleView like NavigationBar

Comment: but isn't bad for the performance of the app? i guess generating a new image each time the view will appear is something negative to the performance. anyway thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: i found a solution that i posted above.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer (seriously by myself). actually it's a trick that i discovered which enables you to enter a label-like text in the toolbar. all you have to do is using Flexible Spaces and tool item objects from the object library. you actually to add two flexible spaces and one item. then situate the item to be between the two spaces in the middle and change the item's style to plain. then you can make an outlet to it to change it's name.